# How can i create an axios instance on Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, next.js

I am trying to create and axios instance so that I don't have to write Authorization header on every request. I am storing access token on localStorage.

I tried creating a file `axiosInstance.ts`

```
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from "axios"

 const service = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/",
      headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage && localStorage.getItem("token")
          ? `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
          : "",
      },
    })
export default service
```

But it throws `localStorage is not defined` error.

So I tried to make this a custom hook like this

`useAxios.ts`

```
function useAxios() {
  const [axiosInstance, setAxiosInstance] = useState<null | AxiosInstance>(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    const service = axios.create({
      baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/",
      headers: {
        Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token")
          ? `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`
          : "",
      },
    })

    setAxiosInstance(service)
  }, [])

  return axiosInstance
}

export default useAxios
```

And when i tried to use it like this it threw an error which says `service.post is not a function`

So when i log the `service/axiosInstance` it logs a get request promise to baseURL. I am not sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: How are you using the hook? Like this?: ```const axiosInstance = useAxios();```?

Comment: @maxeth Yes, i use it like that.

Comment: Are you waiting for the `axiosInstance` to be defined before calling the `post` method? Can you provide the code where you actually use the `useAxios` hook?